# Script laggy to load on older iOS devices only

Tags: javascript, jquery

Script takes a few seconds to load on older iOS devices. I tested on my iPhone 7 and works fine.

```
   $(document).scroll(function () {
   var y = $(this).scrollTop();

   if (y > 300) {
        $('#bottombadge').fadeIn; 
   } 

   else {
        /* (y <= 300) */
        $('#bottombadge').fadeOut();
   }     

});
```

It's mainly the fadeIn that is super slow. Any ideas please? Thank you

Comment: using this <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because `scroll` fires for *every pixel* that's scrolled. Therefore if you scroll 200px you're potentially calling `fadeIn()` 200 times. To fix this you need to 'debounce' the scroll event so that it only happens N ms after scrolling has stopped:

```
var timer;

$(document).scroll(function () {
  var $doc = $(this);
  clearTimeout(timer);
  timer = setTimeout(function() {
    var y = $doc.scrollTop();
    $('#bottombadge')[y > 300 ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut']();
  }, 150);
});
```

Comment: thanks very much Rory. the fadeIn still takes sometime to kick in unfortunately. what I do not understand is that it only happens on older devices such as iPhone 6 etc. completely fine on iPhone 7 and S7. any thoughts please?

Comment: Most likely due to lack of processing power in the mobile JS engine. You could try using CSS to do the fading as that is hardware accelerated

Comment: do I replace the ? 'fadeIn' : 'fadeOut'] with something else?